# Visual Studio Docker Compose - stop and remove containers after debug session ends

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have an ASP.NET Core web app for which I have added logging to ElasticSearch & Kibana.
I am running it on a Windows host and the containers are Linux.

The docker-compose file is set to first start up elastic search, then kibana and then finally the web application - as below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.2
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=true
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.9.2
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://localhost:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  hyena.webapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}hyena_image
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Hyena.WebApp/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:443"
      - "5000:80"
    container_name: "hyena_container" 
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /c/docker/hyena
        target: /data
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
    - elastic

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch-data:
```

When I hit Debug (F5), VS starts everything up and I can see in Docker Desktop that the containers are running and I can see that the apps communicate with each other (i.e. logs from the web app appear in Kibana).

[image]

Now, when I stop Visual Studio debugging, my webapp is no longer accessible through the browser, however both ElasticSearch and Kibana keep on working.

Docker desktop and `docker container ls` command all show that the containers are running.

So, my questions are:

1. If the containers are running, why cannot I access my web app anymore?
2. Why is it only happening with my web app and not with Kibana or ElasticSearch?
3. How can I make VS stop and remove these containers after a debug session?

Kind regards,
Bartosz